# How to cast PE file to "dos_header" structure?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, portable-executable

I'm trying to read in an .exe PE file and map it to header structs.

This is what I have so far:

```cpp
static constexpr uint16_t DOS_HDR_MAGIC = 0x5A4D; 

struct dos_header_t {
    uint16_t                    e_magic;
    uint16_t                    e_cblp;
    uint16_t                    e_cp;
    uint16_t                    e_crlc;
    uint16_t                    e_cparhdr;
    uint16_t                    e_minalloc;
    uint16_t                    e_maxalloc;
    uint16_t                    e_ss;
    uint16_t                    e_sp;
    uint16_t                    e_csum;
    uint16_t                    e_ip;
    uint16_t                    e_cs;
    uint16_t                    e_lfarlc;
    uint16_t                    e_ovno;
    uint16_t                    e_res[ 4 ];
    uint16_t                    e_oemid;
    uint16_t                    e_oeminfo;
    uint16_t                    e_res2[ 10 ];
    uint32_t                    e_lfanew;
};

int main(void) {
    std::ifstream input("./stuff.exe", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary );

    input.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    int file_size = input.tellg();

    char file[file_size];
    input.read(file, file_size);

    struct dos_header_t *dos_header = (struct dos_header_t *)file;

    assert(dos_header->e_magic == DOS_HDR_MAGIC);
}
```

But the assertion fails and printing `e_magic` prints `0`.

Am I casting it wrong? How do I get the assertion to pass?

Comment: Two unrelated problems: 1) `int` might not be big enough to store all possible file sizes; And 2) C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), use either dynamic allocation using `new[]` or (better) use `std::vector`.

Comment: Also, such a cast is undefined behavior.

Comment: Then a possibly related problem: `char` might be signed *or* unsigned, it's implementation specific. So values in your array might not be what you expect. Better use `std::byte` or `std::uint8_t` for your data.

Comment: Oh, and you might need to think about [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) as well, if the file is moved to a different architecture.